# Is there a way to process Lombok-ed source file in codeql

Tags: github, codeql

I am trying to write a code analyzer with codeql(https://securitylab.github.com/tools/codeql),but I account an error which is displayed as flollowing

```
[2021-01-20 15:56:59] [javac-extractor-4576] [WARN] Skipping Lombok-ed source file:
```

so my lombok-ed source file is not include in codeql database

eg.my lombok-ed source file displayed as flollowing

```
public class Test1{
    public static String testOkHttpGet() {
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();

        HttpUrl httpUrl = HttpUrl.parse("http://localhost:8080/demo/list").newBuilder()
                .addQueryParameter("name", "HTTP").build();

        okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder().url(httpUrl.toString()).build();
        try (Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute()) {
            ResponseBody body = response.body();
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            } else {
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    class Student{
        String name;
        String age;
    }

}
```

and the file is not include in src.zip
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vd8li.png)

Comment: Probably has been answered in [this Github issue](https://github.com/github/codeql/issues/4984).

Answer (score 0):

Check if this recent GitHub update would help:

> ### [Code scanning with CodeQL improves support for Java codebases that use Project Lombok](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-09-01-code-scanning-with-codeql-improves-support-for-java-codebases-that-use-project-lombok/) (Sep. 2023)
>
> Code scanning with CodeQL now supports Java codebases that use [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/).
>
> Previously, code scanning users were able to scan Java applications that contained Lombok code, but all the contents of files containing Lombok code were either skipped or users had to apply a workaround to prepare the applications for scanning.
>
> The improved support means that code with Lombok features will be automatically scanned without requiring any workaround.
>
> As more code will now be analyzed by the CodeQL engine, we can establish more accurate data flow (or lack thereof) through Lombok code.
> This might have an impact on the number of alerts produced by a scan.
> The most common scenario is that additional alerts appear in the newly-analyzed code.
> Conversely, there is a very small chance that some existing alerts are closed.
>
> Improved support for Java applications built using Lombok is available for code scanning users on GitHub.com starting today and GitHub Enterprise Server users starting with `3.11`.
> [**CodeQL CLI**](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/codeql-cli) will provide out of the box support starting with the upcoming version `2.14.4`.
> Security researchers can set up the CodeQL CLI and VS Code extension by following [these instructions](https://codeql.github.com/docs/codeql-for-visual-studio-code/setting-up-codeql-in-visual-studio-code/#configuring-access-to-the-codeql-cli).